# About position of the menu and spinner!

Tags: android, menu, spinner

Is there any way to change or to set the position of the menu or spinner's dropdown items?
Why they always show in the center of the screen? How can I change it by my decision?
Asking for help!
Thanks FIRST!

Answer (score 1):

I believe its not possible to change context menu position.

Answer (score 0):

That's because windows were spinner items, dialogs, context menu are shown has floating feature turned on (i.e. [`isFloating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#isFloating%28%29) returns true). And this is a feature, by the way.

You can override this using custom theme on your activity/application and [`windowIsFloating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowIsFloating) attribute.